# Install RPostgreSQL on RHEL 6.5 libpq-fe.h Error

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have RHEL 6.5 Server with an installation of R (3.1.1) & RStudioServer (0.98.1062)

I have postgresql-9.3 installed and handling a large database. In order to connect R to PostgreSQL, I have in the past used the RPostgreSQL (still do on my CentOS 7 Workstation). However, attempting to compile under RHEL 6.5 I get an error

```
In file included from RS-PQescape.c:7:
RS-PostgreSQL.h:23:26: error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

The file is located on my system here:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/libpq-fe.h
```

Libpq is part of the Postgres installation, but RPostgreSQL cannot find it:

```
[root@server /]# yum list libpq*
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
Installed Packages
libpqxx.x86_64     1:4.0.1-1.rhel6                                               @pgdg93
libpqxx-debuginfo.x86_64     1:4.0.1-1.rhel6                                     @pgdg93
libpqxx-devel.x86_64   1:4.0.1-1.rhel6                                           @pgdg93
```

Is there any way to tell RPostgreSQL where to look (symbolic links?) or some other workaround? This should be simple, but I've wasted several hours on this already...

Comment: I ended up looking into the RPostgreSQL configure file in the tarball, searched for the file name the script couldn't find and decided it was easiest to create an environmental variable:           export PG_INCDIR=/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Followup info because I just had the same problem.
Installing `yum install postgresql-devel` resolves the error too.

Comment: worked for me on Mac: brew install postgresql -devel . It needs a space between  "postgresql" and "-devel"

Answer (score 9):

I ended up looking into the RPostgreSQL configure file in the tarball, searched for the file name the script couldn't find and decided it was easiest to create an environmental variable:

> export PG_INCDIR=/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/

Worked like a charm after that.

If you have sudo rights, you could also try:

> yum install postgresql-devel

Comment: If the RPostgreSQL file still can't find the path, try adding symbolic link to location of installed package. For example `sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/ /usr/local/pgsql`