# Install RPostgreSQL on Debian with PostgreSQL 9.4 libpq-fe.h Error

Tags: r, postgresql

I have R (3.1.1) and PostgreSQL 9.4 installed on Debian 7.6.

```
I want to install RPostgreSQL but the compilation fails with the following error:
In file included from RS-PQescape.c:7:0:                                       
RS-PostgreSQL.h:23:26: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory      
compilation terminated.                                                        
make: *** [RS-PQescape.o] Error 1                                              
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RPostgreSQL’                            
* removing ‘/home/mert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RPostgreSQL’
```

A previous question on this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302960/install-rpostgresql-on-rhel-6-5-libpq-fe-h-error) says that the file is included here:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/include/libpq-fe.h
```

I searched on my computer for pgsql and libpq but no such file exists at all:

```
$ locate libpq                              
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/libpqwalreceiver.so                                
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5                                           
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5.7                                         
/usr/share/doc/libpq5 

$ locate pgsql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/plpgsql.so                                         
/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/plpgsql--1.0.sql                           
/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/plpgsql--unpackaged--1.0.sql               
/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/plpgsql.control
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: For the header files you probably need to install postgres-dev

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, `libpq-fe.h` is part of the package `libpq-dev`.

Answer (score 52):

You are missing libpq-dev on your machine. Open a command prompt and install it using apt-get. Once installed try installing RPostgreSQL in R-Studio.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Or for Arch Linux:

```
sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the previous answers, in case of errors even when `libpq-dev` is already installed. On Ubuntu 16.04 with installed `libpq-dev`, my `libpq-fe.h` was sitting in `/usr/include/postgresql/` but the R install packages function still could  not find it. After downloading the latest RPostgreSQL build from CRAN, I looked at its configure file and saw that this folder was specified in it as a likely location for the postgres configuration files which led me to believe that it was a permissions problem, and, yes,

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL RPostgreSQL_0.4-1.tar.gz
```

solved the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install RPostgreSQL on Ubuntu 14.04 using the following:

```
system('gksudo "apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3 libpq-dev"')
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

But if you get an error like:

> libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but
> 14.0-1.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed

You should install first (look carefully at the name above):

```
apt-get install libpq5=12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

and then `apt-get install libpq-dev` again.